# Getting list of all sub windows from tab group

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

i am adding many windows to tab group like this

```
$.tabgroup.open(win, {
 animated : false
 });
```

how can i get list of all windows added to tabgroup ?
some thing like `$.tabgroup.windows` or `$.tabgroup.window.views`  does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,there is no any property present that gives you the windows stack opened in tab group but i would suggest to maintain custom stack...

like....

make one global array then whenever you open window then push that window in a stack and when you close the window then pop it from stack. In that way, you will get all the windows which are opened.

Answer (score 0):

Windows added to TabGroup are stored in [tabs property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-property-tabs).

Check the link to documentation for more detailed info.